# Python itertools.zip_longest with mutable fillvalue

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools, default-value, mutable

In a code that evaluates a web response, I would like to zip elements from several lists. However, the elements of the iterators are `dict`'s.
Therefore, I would like to fill up the missing values also with `dict`'s, but each generated element should have it's own `dict` instance.

The following code groups elements from each list by `itertools.zip_longest`.
As long as there is a non mutable `fillvalue` specified, there is no problem.

```py
import collections
import itertools

l1 = [{"a": 100}, {"b": 200}, {"c": 300}]
l2 = [{"d": 400}]

ll = list(itertools.zip_longest(l1, l2, fillvalue=0))
print(ll)
```

-> `[({'a': 100}, {'d': 400}), ({'b': 200}, 0), ({'c': 300}, 0)]`

Now, when a mutable `fillvalue` is specified, all the `fillvalue`'s share the same instance and so changing one, changes all:

```py
import collections
import itertools

l1 = [{"a": 100}, {"b": 200}, {"c": 300}]
l2 = [{"d": 400}]

ll = list(itertools.zip_longest(l1, l2, fillvalue=dict()))
ll[1][1]["x"] = 150
print(ll)
```

-> `[({'a': 100}, {'d': 400}), ({'b': 200}, {'x': 150}), ({'c': 300}, {'x': 150})]`

To prevent that all the dicts share the same instance I used `copy.deepcopy`:

```py
import collections
import copy
import itertools

l1 = [{"a": 100}, {"b": 200}, {"c": 300}]
l2 = [{"d": 400}]

ll = list(itertools.zip_longest(l1, l2, fillvalue=copy.deepcopy(dict())))
ll[1][1]["x"] = 150
print(ll)
```

-> `[({'a': 100}, {'d': 400}), ({'b': 200}, {'x': 150}), ({'c': 300}, {'x': 150})]`

As a result, still all `dict`'s from the `fillvalue` share the same instance.

I would like to add that `ll = [item or dict() for item in itertools.zip_longest(l1, l2)]` works neither, assuming a fillvalue of `None`.

So, how can I make each `fillvalue` unique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a sentinel value and wrap `zip_longest` in another pipeline.

For example:

```
sentinel = object()
l = list(tuple({} if x is sentinel else x for x in items) for items in zip_longest(l1, l2, fillvalue=sentinel))
```

For this example, you can probably use `None` rather than a custom `sentinel` object.

Comment: In my case I could use a sentinal of `None`, which is the default for the `fillvalue`.
So I could write: `l = list(tuple(x if x is not None else {} for x in items) for items in zip_longest(l1, l2))`

Comment: @WörDuSchnaffzig. Exactly. I prefer positive conditions when possible, so `{} if x is None else x`, but that's just personal aesthetics

Comment: Agree. Should have seen that.

Answer (score 2):

You can't teach `zip_longest` to copy the `dict`s for you. You have to copy them yourself (this will also dissociate the original values from `l2`), e.g.:

```
ll = [(d1, d2.copy()) for d1, d2 in itertools.zip_longest(l1, l2, fillvalue={})]
```

or just make them from scratch on demand (this will dissociate empty `dict`s from `l2`, leaving the rest aliases, which may or may not be what you want):

```
ll = [(d1, d2 or {}) for d1, d2 in itertools.zip_longest(l1, l2)]
```

An alternate that preserves aliasing perfectly would be the more verbose:

```
ll = [(d1, {} if d2 is None else d2) for d1, d2 in itertools.zip_longest(l1, l2)]
```

If `l1` might be shorter than `l2`, you'd apply similar transformations to `d1` in each listcomp.

Comment: I think this is the same approach like the one from @MadPhysicist but only for two source lists. This has the advantage that it is easier to grasp. It then can be generalized.

Comment: @WörDuSchnaffzig: Yeah, we posted around the same time, and after edits (to remove unnecessary non-default `fillvalue`), my solution #3 ended up essentially the same as theirs for the case where `l1` and `l2` are guaranteed not to contain `None` as a value (matching the OP's scenario), removing the need for a custom sentinel. Personally, I like option #1 for many scenarios, as it limits the risk of aliasing between `dict`s in `ll` and `l2` causing "spooky action at a distance"; you could remove that risk entirely by using `copy.deepcopy((l1, l2))` as the expression to produce.

Comment: But if the goal is minimum overhead, and aliasing is *desired* when possible, then option #3 is the way to go. Option #2 splits the difference, performing partial aliasing (for the non-empty `dict` inputs), in exchange for the most succinct code (the speed *should* be similar to #3, but #3 might conceivably be faster if truthiness testing a `dict` [which requires looking at its length] ends up slower than `None` checking it (which is a strict pointer comparison).

Answer (score 0):

Having fun with more itertools, chaining a dict-producer onto the lists. That turns each list into an iterator of its elements followed by infinitely many new empty dicts. Zipping them gives the desired result, except it doesn't stop when all list elements have been used. So I use `zip_longest` to give me an iterator of the desired length, and use that (in `compress`) to limit the data.

```py
from itertools import starmap, chain, repeat, compress, zip_longest

l1 = [{"a": 100}, {"b": 200}, {"c": 300}]
l2 = [{"d": 400}]

lists = l1, l2
dicts = starmap(dict, repeat(()))
ll = list(compress(
    zip(*map(chain, lists, repeat(dicts))),
    zip_longest(*lists)
))

ll[1][1]['e'] = 500
print(ll)
```

Output ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=PVBBasMwEKTXfcXiS6Sggu02UAp9STBFdZRGsLaEtD20oS_pJZf2UX1N14pVocPMMjM77NdPfOdTmC-X7zc-3j783phjChN6dolDoIx-iiExZrZpstHgeLJ-NphcdJaFhikml7PBDx-fKcyvLjMAdfiE-3Njm0fs2vbT4Ll5EdyveBR8J3gA6q_Kg0zuywTIZ84ypc4g9XDwY6FrBbXwWkAprTUQLWpxqVpHAcqTSmq7WNbSJfjfWnLFbqq21lfbItQg0ZK974blb9xmkDW7toWY_MyKSF-Ptt6u3vAP)):

```
[({'a': 100}, {'d': 400}),
 ({'b': 200}, {'e': 500}),
 ({'c': 300}, {})]
```

Alternatively, using `islice` to stop at the max length:

```py
ll = list(islice(
    zip(*map(chain, lists, repeat(dicts))),
    max(map(len, lists))
))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=PVBLasMwEKVbnaGLwZvIRQHbbSEUepLgheooZGBsCWkCbUNP0k026aF6mo5ku2IWbx7vI-b7J3zwyU_X6-3Mx-3u9-7-GP0IyC6y95QAx-AjQ2IbRxsMDCeLk4HogrNsABPh4JSiFl5hf6ls9QJt03wZuFRvgrsFD4IfBfeKull5EOapMIowcRKWWgPUqQMOZV06dd7XRq3rulZEWS0uPfdrBfI-MeiHbFj-WGL_jSVVzKZoR_uus5TcKpRYGYnet32ejdv00vLcNCpEnFgT1fORllutN_sD)

Comment: This looks heavily elaborated and not easy to understand. Could you explain in a few words?

Comment: @WörDuSchnaffzig Added more explanation.

Comment: @WörDuSchnaffzig And added a simpler alternative at the end. (I'm used to working with iterators, where I don't have the luxury of calling `len()`).